# EF support to join table by condition?

Tags: entity-framework

I have 3 tables as following:

http://images.cnblogs.com/cnblogs_com/guozili/390921/o_ef.png

Can ef support as following:

```
class Product
int Id {get;set;}
string Name {get;set;}
List<Picture> Picture {get;set;}

class Picture
...
[ForeignKey("Product.ProductId".....when type=1)] 
int ModelId {get;set;}
```

i hope it could work by mapping attribute or such as ".ToTable()...WithMany(c=>..).Map(....."
could ef did these ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be achieve (but not exactly) with a TPH strategy, something like

```
public class Picture {
    public Int32 Id {get; set;}
    public String URL {get; set;}
}

public class ProductPicture : Picture {
    public virtual Product {get; set;}
}

public class CompanyPicture : Picture {
    public virtual Company {get; set;}
}
```

and when building your model

```
protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Picture>()
        .Map<ProductPicture>(e => e.Requires("Type").HasValue(1))
        .Map<CompanyPicture>(e => e.Requires("Type").HasValue(2))
}
```

In this case you will have one table with:

- A discriminator column
- one FK to Product
- one FK to Company